# MySQL 8 fails to start: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error

Tags: mysql

I'm getting the following errors after running `sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables` on my Ubuntu Desktop (my PC, no a server):

```
2019-03-11T09:43:13.463024Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.15)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2019-03-11T09:46:23.705247Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.15) starting as process 3141
2019-03-11T09:46:23.717873Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012935] [InnoDB] Database upgrade cannot be accomplished in read-only mode.
2019-03-11T09:46:23.717884Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.
2019-03-11T09:46:23.717906Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-011013] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine.
2019-03-11T09:46:23.718040Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2019-03-11T09:46:23.718101Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2019-03-11T09:46:23.718366Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.15)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

This is how `my.cnf` looks like:

```
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/

[mysqld]
innodb_force_recovery = 6
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 10M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 10M
innodb_log_file_size = 1000M
```

I already backed up the `/var/lib/mysql` directory which contains the important data, but I would like to make a mysql dump as well.

How can I start the mysql server in a minimal way so that I can export the databases?

Comment: Are you doing thsi as part of upgrading from an older version of MySQL

Comment: @RiggsFolly Not really... what happened was that the MySQL server simply crashed... I'm trying to recover the data and then try a fresh installation.